# Python3: How to turn PRINTed item into variable, and how to PRINT the VARIABLE into a cell in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

my goal is to scrape data from multiple websites using Python3 and copy the results of the PRINT function to any cell in excel. I'm a newbie in Python so please bear with me, here are my questions:

**1. How to turn PRINTed item into VARIABLE?**

**2. How to PRINT the VARIABLE into a cell in Excel?**

I've tried to run below code however I have encountered below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\programname.py", line 53, in <module>
    sheet['A1'] = variable1
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Note that I am not intending to print all text data in each website, as I still have to figure out the parsing of the items that I need to get.

Much thanks in advance for the help, guys!

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer
import csv
import requests
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

url = ['https://example1.com', 'https://example2.com']
wb = openpyxl.Workbook('sample_excel.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

for each in url:
    response = requests.get(each)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    data = soup
    try:
        variable1 = str(data.get_text())
    except AttributeError:
        print("No data text found")

sheet['A1'] = variable1
wb.save('sample_excel.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of any errors you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you Charlie and apologies for not giving this beforehand. The full traceback is below, I've updated the original question as well with the full error. Thanks!                                                                                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\programname.py", line 53, in <module>
    sheet['A1'] = variable1
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Comment: The line number in the exception tells us that the code posted does not correspond 1:1 with yours. But it also tells you the problem: `sheet['A1'] is None`. So, somewhere in your code you've reassigned this.

Comment: @Bacorrito: You can't pass the filename to `.Workbook('sample_excel.xlsx')`, this get passed to parameter `write_only=` which prevents to add a empty Worksheet. Use `.Workbook()`, the filename to save to goes into `wb.save(...` only.